# Laravel: translate resource URLs

Tags: php, laravel, routes, crud

When a resource controller is created in Laravel like this:

```php
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
```

We get URLs like:

- foo/create
- foo/store
- foo/{id}/edit
- foo/{id}/update
- ...

I would like to translate some of these routes to get something like:

- foo/**nouveau**
- foo/store
- foo/{id}/**modifier**
- foo/{id}/update

This code is working:

```php
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController', array(
    'names' => array(
        'create'    => 'nouveau',
        'edit'      => 'modifier',
        ...
    )
));
```

The problem here is the `edit` route: I don't know how to make it works with an `{id}` like `foo/{id}/modifier`.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout my package: https://github.com/doitonlinemedia/TranslatableRoutes pretty easy to use.

You can call the resource routes like:

`TranslatableRoute::resource('recipe', 'recepten', 'RecipeController');`

Where the second argument is the translated name and the first defines the name of your routes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Now it is proper, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on Laravel documentation at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-localizing-resource-uris

## Localizing Resource URIs

By default, `Route::resource` will create resource URIs using English verbs. If you need to localize the `create` and `edit` action verbs, you may use the `Route::resourceVerbs` method. This may be done in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::resourceVerbs([
        'create' => 'nouveau',
        'edit' => 'modifier',
    ]);
}
```

Once the verbs have been customized, a resource route registration such as  Route::resource('foo', 'FooController') will produce the following URIs:

`/foo/nouveau`

`/foo/{id}/modifier`

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible using `resource` method. You will need to create those routes manually using `trans / Lang::get`, for example:

```
Route::get('foo/{id}/'.trans('routes.edit'), 'FooController@edit');
```

The names you can pass here in 3rd parameters are for named routes and don't have anything in common with urls, if you used something named routes as you showed you can now use:

```
URL::route('nouveau', 1);
```

and it will generate `foo/1/edit` url. If you didn't use here names you should use then:

```
URL::route('foo.edit',1);
```

to create this url but it's the only difference, no url impact here.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your are just missing the namespacing on the routes. When Laravel generates a resource it creates the namespace as well. So instead of `foo.create` you would have `foo.nouveau`.

```
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController', array(
  'names' => array(
    'create'  => 'foo.nouveau',
    'edit'    => 'foo.modifier'
  )
));
```

This can also be [referenced here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) in the Laravel docs